# How do you make elements expand to fill the cross axis in flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to have elements fill up the cross axis in flexbox. In the example below I have a fixed-height item taking up a whole row, and two items taking up the next.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin: 0;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
div {
  border: 3px solid red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
div#a {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="a" style="background-color:green">AAA</div>
  <div id="b" style="background-color:blue">BBB</div>
  <div id="c" style="background-color:yellow">CCC</div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you change the `align-content` on `body` to `stretch` you can see the effects of the body min-height - the second row will stick to the bottom. However, there is now a gap between the rows.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin: 0;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
}
div {
  border: 3px solid red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
div#a {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="a" style="background-color:green">AAA</div>
  <div id="b" style="background-color:blue">BBB</div>
  <div id="c" style="background-color:yellow">CCC</div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to remove this gap so that blocks B and C take up all remaining space.

Comment: Basically, using the current structure, flexbox doesn't have an option for that...and it's not really logical that it should.If the height of the first pseudo-row is known you could use `calc` to set the height of the second pseudo-row. Otherwise, change the structure.

Comment: Oh yeah! I never used calc because of compatability concerns but if I'm using flexbox calc is pretty much guaranteed to work. If you post this as an answer I'll tick it.

Comment: Nope never mind - `calc` doesn't seem to work here. It's taking the size flex already gives it for me...

Comment: Calc doesn't work with `min-height`..use height:100% instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, using the current structure, flexbox doesn't have an option for that...and it's not really logical that it should.

One the other hand, if the height of the first pseudo-row is known you could use `calc` to set the height of the second pseudo-row by setting the height of the second div....*but it's not really a "flexbox solution*".

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  border: 3px solid red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
div#a {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
div#b {
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="a" style="background-color:green">AAA</div>
  <div id="b" style="background-color:blue">BBB</div>
  <div id="c" style="background-color:yellow">CCC</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Works, but only with `height` not `min-height`, guess that's my next question

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```css
html {
  min-height: 100vh;  
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#a {
  flex: 0 1 100px;  
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.group div {
  flex: 1; 
}
```

```html
<div id="a" style="background-color:green">AAA</div>
<div class="group">
  <div id="b" style="background-color:blue">BBB</div>
  <div id="c" style="background-color:yellow">CCC</div>
</div>
```